# Permission to access sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

So I have a website for internal use which tracks a bunch of stats for employees.  One of these is whether they are missing any reports.  Since the list of items that don't have reports yet only gets updated every couple days, and there is a 3 day grace period on these reports, I am comparing the Date (releaseDt) that the item was logged as missing a report to the last time the database was updated (@lastupdate).  This way, if the reports database hasn't updated but the report is complete, the website isn't ratting someone out for missing a report.

The SQL code works fine with admin level privledges, but for obvious reasons I'm not letting the ASP.NET account have server admin level.

I have set up a SQL account that the ASP.NET C# code uses to log in, and the permissions for everything else are fine. (Read access only for the specific databases it uses.)  I can't figure out what to give it access to in order to have access to read this specific dynamic management view.

Would appreciate suggestions using either Management Studio, or using a `GRANT` SQL statement.

This appears to have related information on the view in question:

[sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755.aspx)

```
DECLARE @lastupdate datetime
     SELECT @lastupdate = last_user_update from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
     WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('MissingReport')

SELECT 
    COALESCE(Creator, 'Total') AS 'Creator',
    COUNT(*) AS Number, 
    '$' + CONVERT(varchar(32), SUM(Cost), 1) AS 'Cost' 
    FROM MissingReport 
    WHERE NOT( 
        [bunch of conditions that make something exempt from needing a report]
        OR
        (
            DATEDIFF(day,ReleaseDt,@lastupdate) <= 3
        )
    )
    GROUP BY Creator WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Just for pedantic clarity, that is a `dynamic management view`, not a `system table`.

Comment: Sure, I don't think the code or the backstory are relevant either - the question could be a one- or two-liner without losing any meaning.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't grant `SELECT` on DMVs, since this is prevented by policy for server-scoped DMVs:

```
GRANT SELECT ON sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats TO peon;
```

Results in:

> Msg 4629, Level 16, State 10, Line 1
>   Permissions on server scoped catalog views or system stored procedures or extended stored procedures can be granted only when the current database is master.

The [BOL page you referenced](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755.aspx) tells you that you need to grant `VIEW SERVER STATE`. You would apply this to the login from master:

```
USE master;
GO
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO peon;
-- if it's a Windows login then:
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO [Domain\peon];
```

But there isn't a way to do this per database. Not that you should be all that concerned, since even if someone could figure out how to hack into your server with the ASP.NET account credentials, all they can do is *see* server state, they can't change anything.

Comment: Sounds right, tried that, but my admin login (which has `sysadmin` server role - just doublechecked - gives the error `Grantor does not have GRANT permission.`

Comment: @sylverfyre what does this yield: `SELECT permission_name FROM sys.fn_my_permissions(NULL, N'server');` (Don't list them in a comment, but how many rows are there, and are important things like `ALTER ANY LOGIN` missing?)

Comment: Yeah, no `ALTER ANY LOGIN`  Odd, because when I look at the corresponding menu in management studio, I have `ALTER ANY LOGIN` as well as all the others like `ALTER ANY CREDENTIAL` etc.

Comment: Are there any checkboxes in the `Deny` column? Any chance you're a member of a group that has been denied this right? (Deny always wins.) What does the `Effective` tab say? I don't really trust the UI anyway, and that's not where I'd go to check these things (even though it seems easier). However tracking down *why* something isn't there might prove to be a bit tougher, especially if it's a `DENY` cascaded down via group/role membership.

Comment: Worked when I used the main admin account instead of my personal db admin account.  Apparently, while I had been GRANTed permissions for DOING things on the server, I didn't have WITH GRANT for all of them (except for the db's i created myself)  When I examined the table you pointed me at more closely, I noticed this.

Comment: @sylverfyre yeah the `WITH GRANT` part is important for your use case.