# SQL Server 2012 - Permission for access to sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats in Contained Database

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

In a contained database, how to I grant users read access on this table?

I am trying to create a function to get the date a table was last updated, but when contained users run it, it fails with error 297 ‘The user does not have permission to perform this action.’.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [MGMT].[GetLastObjectUpdateTime] (@ObjectName NVARCHAR(100))
RETURNS DATETIME
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS 
BEGIN
        DECLARE @Result DATETIME

        SELECT  @result = MAX(last_user_update)
        FROM    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
        WHERE   OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(@ObjectName)

        RETURN @Result
END
```

(code from : http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/09/sql-server-find-last-date-time-updated-for-any-table/#comment-684267 )

Comment: They or pehaps public (or some other group) need execute privilege on the function and references permission on the contained table. Not clear who's got what from your post.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473907/permission-to-access-sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats

Comment: Users are members of role that has execute permission. To grant view server state will mean that I am breaking some of the containment features as I will have to run grant on each server I attach the contained db to.

Answer (score 0):

I would try granting the owner the server permission VIEW SERVER STATE which is [needed to use that view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755.aspx).

```
USE master;
GO
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO [owner login]
GO
```

Comment: Although technically this would work, it would break the containment features of the database. One would need to run this script on every server the database gets migrated to.